# Hide keyboard when orientation is set to portrait

Tags: java, android, rotation, keyboard

The closest I got to is:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    //Some other code
}
```

But that doesn't work. In this case, even if no input has focus, the keyboard will be pulled up, once the orientation is changed to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Use this util listener code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;

public class KeyboardUtil implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {
static public interface KeyboardListener {
    public void onKeyboardVisible(boolean visible);
}

private int mHeight;
private boolean mVisible;
private View mRootView;
private KeyboardListener mListener;

public KeyboardUtil(Activity activity) {
    mVisible = false;
    mHeight = 0;
    if (activity == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        mRootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView()
                .findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        mRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setListener(KeyboardListener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    if (mHeight == 0) {
        mHeight = mRootView.getMeasuredHeight();
        return;
    }

    if (mListener == null) {
        return;
    }

    int height = mRootView.getHeight();

    if (!mVisible && mHeight > (height + 100)) {
        mVisible = true;
        mListener.onKeyboardVisible(mVisible);
        mHeight = height;
    } else if (mVisible && mHeight < (height - 100)) {
        mVisible = false;
        mListener.onKeyboardVisible(mVisible);
        mHeight = height;
    }
}
}
```

Below code use in you activity

```
new KeyboardUtil(context).setListener(keyboardListener);

KeyboardUtil.KeyboardListener keyboardListener = new KeyboardUtil.KeyboardListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyboardVisible(boolean visible) {
     // get configuration here and 
     if(config is portrait)
         hideSoftKeyboard(this); // Provide you activity context
    }
};

public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how am I supposed to use this. The class will be written after the MainActivity. Does the 2nd block code needs to be written when I want the keyboard to be down?

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

View view = this.getCurrentFocus();

```
        try {
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: insted of 0 u try this ? --> InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS

Comment: it make popup to keyboad if there is no keyboard aviable ?

in my case it working if there is keyboad on screen already it remove and it does not  pop up keyboard on .

Comment: Yes, the keyboard is up even if no input has focus.

Comment: have u used this permission on mainifest file ? android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"

Comment: Yes, but not as a permission - but inside `<activity>`.

Comment: yeah that  is permission it will invoke all time when ever activity is re create and it make appear keypad on , it used to strictly  open keyboard even if there is no focused filed

Comment: put ur Condition in Side onResume

Comment: Then, how to solve this? I just tried changing the value to "stateVisible", but the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: put ur Condition in Side onResume and check state and just use this code it may work

Comment: public String getRotation(Context context){
    final int rotation = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
           switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                return "portrait";
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                return "landscape";
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                return "reverse portrait";
            default:
                return "reverse landscape";
            }
        }

Comment: above code determaine u ur state
just call it on onResume 

if(getRotation.equals("portrait")){
 
//put my Code here 

}